# how to choose one of two objects in int main if they both show up in the screen?

Tags: c++, if-statement, int

So I'm almost finish with my college project but they want me to ask the user which car he wants and with that data i have to create the object using the parameters that i previously asked. But if the user wants the "Audi A7" or the "BMW X6" i need to create an object using the **set** methods. The problem is that both of the objects show in screen. PD: Sorry for my bad english.

```
    #include <string>
    #include <iostream>
    #include <sstream>  
    #include <iomanip>
    #include <locale>

    using namespace std;
    //Esto es solo para que sea puede ver los dos puntos en el precio. 
    //Tuve que usar esta clase porque me salia error usando s.imbue(std::locale(""));

class punto : public numpunct<char>
{
private:
    virtual char do_thousands_sep() const
    {
        return '.';
    }

    virtual string do_grouping() const
    {
        return "\03";
    }
};
    //Clase Vehiculo
    class Vehiculo {

    private:
        string extras;
        string marca;

    public:
        //Constructor Sin Parametros
        Vehiculo()     
        {
            extras = "Indefinido";
            marca = "Indefinido";
        }

        //Constructor Con Parametros
        Vehiculo(string pExtras, string pMarca)
        {                                      
            extras = pExtras;        
            marca = pMarca;
        }
        //Metodos Set
        void setExtras (string pExtras) {
            extras = pExtras;
        }
        void setMarca (string pMarca) {
            marca = pMarca;
        }
        //Metodos Get
        string getExtras() {
            return extras;
        }
        string getMarca() {
            return marca;
        }
        //Metodos De Calculo
        int Seleccion() {
        if (marca == "Audi A7" || marca == "audi a7")
            return (1);
        else
        if (marca == "Alfa Romero Guilietta" || marca == "alfa romero guilietta")
            return (2);
        else
        if (marca == "Mitsubishi Montero Wagon" || marca == "mitsubishi montero wagon")
            return (3);
        else
        if (marca == "BMW X6" || marca == "bmw x6")
            return (4);
        else
        if (marca == "Mercedes Benz Clase GLS" || marca == "mercedes benz clase gls")
            return (5);
        else
        if (marca == "Volvo XC90" || marca == "volvo xc90")
            return (6);
        else
            return 0;
        }


        string tipodeMarca(){
            switch(Seleccion()){
            case 1: return "Audi A7";
            case 2: return "Alfa Romero Guilietta";
            case 3: return "Mitsubishi Montero Wagon";
            case 4: return "BMW X6";
            case 5: return "Mercedes Benz Clase GLS";
            case 6: return "Volvo XC90";
            default: return "No existe";
            }
        }

        string tipodeEstilo(){
            switch(Seleccion()){
            case 1: return "Sedan";
            case 2: return "Hatchback";
            case 3: return "4x4";
            case 4: return "4x4";
            case 5: return "4x4";
            case 6: return "4x4";
            default: return " No existe";
            }
        }
        string tipodeMotor(){
            switch(Seleccion()){
            case 1: return "Gasolina";
            case 2: return "Gasolina";
            case 3: return "Diesel";
            case 4: return "Diesel";
            case 5: return "Diesel";
            case 6: return "Diesel";
            default: return " No existe";
            }
        }
        string tipodeVelocidades(){
            switch(Seleccion()){
            case 1: return "7";
            case 2: return "7";
            case 3: return "6";
            case 4: return "8";
            case 5: return "7";
            case 6: return "8";
            default: return "No existe";
            }
        }
        string tipodeColor(){
            switch(Seleccion()){
            case 1: return "Negro";
            case 2: return "Rojo";
            case 3: return "Gris";
            case 4: return "Gris";
            case 5: return "Blanco";
            case 6: return "Blanco";
            default: return " No existe";
            }
        }
        string tipodeCilindraje(){
            switch(Seleccion()){
            case 1: return " 3000 cc";
            case 2: return " 1,472 cc";
            case 3: return " 2,800 cc";
            case 4: return " 3000 cc";
            case 5: return " 2,987 cc";
            case 6: return " 2500 cc";
            default: return " No existe";
            }
        }
        string PrecioTotal(){
            switch(Seleccion()){
            case 1: return " $105.000";
            case 2: return "  $65.000";
            case 3: return "  $54.900";
            case 4: return " $125.000";
            case 5: return " $129.000";
            case 6: return " $85.900";
            default: return " No existe";
            }
        }

        //Precio En Colones
        double PreEnCol() {
        int eleccion = Seleccion();
            if (eleccion == 1)
                return (105.000*562);
            else if (eleccion == 2)
                return (65.000*562);
            else if (eleccion == 3) 
                return (54.000*562);
            else if (eleccion == 4) 
                return (125.000*562);
            else if (eleccion == 5)
                return (129.000*562);
            else if (eleccion == 6)
                return (85.900*562);
        }

        //Precio Sin Extras
        double PreSinFe() {
        double dinero = PreEnCol();
            return (dinero + ((dinero*18)/100));
        }

        double PreConFe() {
        double dinero = PreEnCol();
            return (dinero + ((dinero*48)/100));
        }

        double Decision() {
            if (extras == "Si" || extras == "si")
                return PreConFe();
            if (extras == "No" || extras == "no" )
                return PreSinFe();
        }

        string toString(){
            stringstream s;
            s<<endl;
            s<<"   "<<tipodeMarca()<<endl<<endl;
            s<<" Estilo: "<<tipodeEstilo()<<endl;
            s<<" Motor: "<<tipodeMotor()<<endl;
            s<<" Velocidades: "<<tipodeVelocidades()<<endl;
            s<<" Color: "<<tipodeColor()<<endl;
            s<<" Cilindraje:"<<tipodeCilindraje()<<endl;
            s<<" Precio:"<<PrecioTotal()<<endl;
            return s.str();
        }
        ~Vehiculo (){
        }
    };
    int main() {

            string extras, marca;

            cout<<endl<<" Por favor eliga uno de los siguientes vehiculos:"<<endl<<endl;
            cout<<" 1) Audi A7"<<endl;
            cout<<" 2) Alfa Romero Guilietta"<<endl;
            cout<<" 3) Mitsubishi Montero Wagon"<<endl;
            cout<<" 4) BMW X6 "<<endl;
            cout<<" 5) Mercedes Benz Clase GLS"<<endl;
            cout<<" 6) Volvo XC90"<<endl;
            cout<<"___________________________________________________"<<endl<<endl;
            cout<<" Escriba el nombre del vehiculo deseado: "; getline(cin,marca); cout<<endl;
            cout<<" Le gustaria agregarle los extras? "<<endl<<endl; cout<<" "; cin>>extras;
            cout<<"___________________________________________________";

            //Constructor con parametros

            Vehiculo Auto1 (extras,marca);

            cout<<endl<<Auto1.toString()<<endl;
            locale comma_locale(std::locale(), new punto());
            cout.imbue(comma_locale);
            cout<<setprecision(3)<<fixed<< " El precio final es: "<<Auto1.Decision()<<" CRC"<<endl;
            cout<<"___________________________________________________";

            //Constructor Sin Parametros

            Vehiculo Auto2;

            Auto2.setMarca(marca);
            Auto2.setExtras(extras);
            cout<<endl<<Auto2.toString()<<endl;
            cout.imbue(comma_locale);
            cout<<setprecision(3)<<fixed<< " El precio final es: "<<Auto2.Decision()<<" CRC"<<endl;
            cout<<"___________________________________________________";

            return 0;
        }
```

Comment: Not really sure what your question is. I do wonder what you plan to do when the user types "zebra" for his car selection though, since you aren't checking for valid input. I'd hope a final project for college would have progressed that far. Also please see https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve.

Comment: well this is just the int main. i had to create a class "Vehicle" and there is where i have all the progress. and if the user types "zebra" it will only show "The vehicle is not in stock". my problem is that i need only one object in the screen but they both appear.

Comment: Well that sounds like bad design. Why is your vehicle class concerned with console input and output? It should be able to do whatever it does no matter if the data came from the console, from disk, or a database, if designed with proper OO principles. Either way, you'll need to include the complete minimal example listing. We have scroll bars.

Comment: Mmm i have very very basic knowledge of c++ because im in my first semester in college but i only do what the instructions ask me. it says that the class must contain all the methods of calculation and that we should use the switch (case 1 = Audi A7 and so on...) but the only thing that i'm missing the objects. but if you want i can show the important parts of the class

Comment: Oh, I thought it was a _final_ college project. Makes more sense now. Edit and include all the code in your post and I will try to figure out what your problem might be.

Comment: wait i forgot to add something

Comment: Your class' constructors, gets, and sets, look OK, for someone new to C++. I am not sure what the "The problem is that both of the objects show in screen. " means. Can you try rephrasing the question? What behavior are you seeing and what are you expecting?

Comment: in other words i'm trying to say if there is a way to make this: if the car is not "audi" or "bmw" then show  Vehiculo Auto1.  If it is then show Vehiculo Auto2.

Answer (score 0):

I am making a guess at what you are asking, but I think you are looking for an if statement that controls how the vehicle is constructed.

```
if( marca == "Audi A7" || marca == "BMW X6" )
{
    Vehiculo auto2;

    auto2.setMarca(marca);
    auto2.setExtras(extras);
    cout<<endl<<auto2.toString()<<endl;
    // etc. etc.
}
else
{
    Vehiculo auto1 (extras,marca);
    cout<<endl<<auto1.toString()<<endl;
    // etc. etc.
}
```

Alternatively, maybe your instructor is looking for something like

```
Vehiculo auto(extra, marca);
if( marca == "Audi A7" || marca == "BMW X6" )
{
    auto.setMarca(marca);
    auto.setExtras(extras);
}

cout<<endl<<auto2.toString()<<endl;
// etc. etc.
```

But that would be redundant since you already set the members with the constructor.

Hope that helps.

Comment: wow, it really helped!!!. i tried doing something simillar but i always write something like "string Object() {                                                                                 
                                 if (.........)   }                                                                 Because i thought you can't use if without a function, but thankfully i was wrong!!. Thank man!!

Comment: No problem. Glad it helped.